# can't access mbean when objectname uses a wildcard

Tags: java, regex, jmx, objectname

I am having an issue accessing an mbean using ObjectName expression matching. The following code successfully sets boolean b:

```
ObjectName objName =
    new ObjectName("UnifiedSystem-search Cluster Control l-c:class=myclass");
boolean b = (boolean)myMBeanServer.invoke(objName, "areAlertsSuppressed");
```

The problem is that the mbeanname changes depending on coding environment. The name only changes slightly, however, which can easily be handled by the built-in expression matching that ObjectNames support. The following code (in the same environment as above) throws an InstanceNotFoundException:

```
ObjectName objName =
    new ObjectName("UnifiedSystem-search Cluster Control *:class=myclass");
boolean b = (boolean)myMBeanServer.invoke(objName, "areAlertsSuppressed")
```

Any ideas how I can get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Can't access mbean when objectname uses a wildcard

As far as I know, `ObjectName` does not handle any wildcard patterns with the `invoke` method.  You are going to have to use the `myMBeanServer.queryNames(...)` method to find the beans that match your pattern.  Then you can call `invoke` with the specific name.

```
Set<ObjectName> nameSet = myMBeanServer.queryNames(new ObjectName(
       "UnifiedSystem-search Cluster Control *:class=myclass"), null);
// then use the first name from the set
// some error checking is needed here to make sure there is a name in the set
myMBeanServer.invoke(nameSet.iterator().next(), "areAlertsSuppressed")
```

Comment: +1. Yes, this is correct. You need to use queryNames() which returns a Set, while using wildcards .